# MetroEEG Data acquisition rate

Tags: windows-phone-8, bluetooth, microsoft-metro, windows-phone

I have used [metroEEG](http://metroeeg.codeplex.com/) for a Windows Phone 8 app which connects the portable [Mindwave mobile](http://www.neurosky.com/products/mindwavemobile.aspx) to the windows phone via bluetooth. By default the metroEEG library sets the data acquisition rate for the Mindwave EEG to 1Hz, whereas the Mindwave can support a refresh rate of upto 100Hz.

I've looked at the sourcecode for metroEEG but have had no luck. How do I set the data acquisition rate from the Mindwave to 100Hz?

Answer (score 1):

So Mindwave Mobile does provide with 512 updates every second (per the [documentation](http://wearcam.org/ece516/mindset_communications_protocol.pdf), page 8). However, the update that's provided that often is the "raw wave sample" and not the "Data Payload Structure". The Data Payload Structure is provides every 1 second after 512 raw wave samples.

From what I could tell when doing testing the raw wave samples are completely identical to each other in rapid intervals. You can see that here in the following print out: 
[image: print out from Mindwave Mobile]

MetroEEG filters out the raw wave sample as noise and focuses in on the data payload structure using simple string actions. To see how the actual formatting is done feel free to read [Explaining how MetroEEG works](http://metroeeg.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Standalone&referringTitle=Documentation).

You can pull down the MetroEEG source and instead of filtering for "UsefulDataPacket" just doing whatever string manipulations you'd like to get any piece of data starting with a [170,170,4] array. Be aware though that C#/WP won't support that much string processing so you'll still have to filter out some results.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, do you know why the raw wave samples are identical here? Since if I connect the Mindwave mobile to a PC, I can get a refresh rate of 100Hz with correct (non identical values).